# Convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^\infty {1\over(\log n)^{\log n}}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I've been working through exercises in  Chapter 8 of Apostol's Mathematical Analysis.  Exercise 8.15 gives a number series to be tested for convergence.  I've gotten most of them but I'm stuck on

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{1\over(\log n)^{\log n}}.$$

The root test is in conclusive, and the things I can think of to compare with have the wrong inequality.  I thought I had proven divergence by the integral test, but something was wrong because according to Wolfram Alpha, this converges.  Hint, anyone?

P.S. Looking to avoid Cauchy condensation test.

Comment: Is it $\log(n^{\log n})$ or $\log(n)^{\log(n)}$?

Comment: The latter, $(\log n)^{\log n}$.

Comment: Why to avoid the wonderful condensation test? It, together with the $\;n$-th root test, pretty easily tell us there's convergence.

Comment: Well, yes you're correct, but Apostol doesn't cover it. So, there must be a way to do the problem without that test.

Comment: You're right that your integral test must be wrong, since it seems to be converging to $\approx 5.7169706$.

Comment: Yes, that is the result I get from Wolfram Alpha

Comment: Mathematica did a convergence test, and it came back true also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$(\log n)^{\log n} = n^{\log\log n} $$
and as soon as $\log\log n > 1$, you can compare your series with a converging one.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\log\log n>2$ to compare it with $\frac{1}{x^2}$

Comment: @avz2611:$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^{1.00000001}}$ is converging, too.

Comment: oh i did not know that , so the exponent if greater than one , series converges?

Comment: @avz2611: exactly.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Cauchy condensation Test

$\sum u(n)$ and $\sum u(a^n) a^n$ converge/diverge together for $a>0$.

Hence, test $\sum \dfrac {1}{(\log a^{n})^{ \log a^n  }} \cdot a^n$ for convergence.